# Derivatives of polar coordinates

Tags: physics, polar-coordinates

I've got a problem for which I'm trying to calculate $\ddot r$.

The problem is right here for the sake of reference.[image: http://i.imgur.com/5tYaRv7.png]

---

So far, I've got that:
$$\ddot r=\frac{d}{dt}v_r=\frac{dv_r}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$$

And since:
$$\dot r= \frac{dr}{dt}$$

I simplified down to:
$$\ddot r=\dot r \frac{dv_r}{dr}$$

Now I'm stuck, because I want to assume $v_r$ is a constant, in which case the whole $\ddot r$ term goes to zero. When I do this I get the wrong answer, however.

How could I take the derivative of $v_r$ with respect to $r$ in this situation?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: this is a question suitable for http://physics.stackexchange.com/. It can't be consider as attaining to the specifications of "physics" tag, nor of "polar-coordinate" one, since your problem is related to the fact you have attacked in a bad way the problem: you haven't specified the frame of reference and, consequently, you have't written the equation of motion. (by means of which solution appears clear.) So I suggest you to move the question on physics.stackexchange, where I, or someone else, can give you the complete solution. (that I have already written.)